# angular.js:13708 SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 130

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

this is my controller in angularjs

```js
(function(){
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("testApp")
        .controller("testAppCtrl", function($scope , $http){
            $http.get('/data/testapp.json').then(function(data){ 
                //$scope.testapps = testapp.data;
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
})();
```

and i face this error

```
angular.js:13708 SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 130
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Please share the JSON from `/data/testapp.json` with us.  My guess is that there is an unexpected token 'p' at position 130.

Comment: please share the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json file has invalid code.You are missing quots around posted and contact also in the and extra , is inserted this should be like

```
[{
"id": "1",
"title": "test1",
"description": "test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 test 1 ",
"price": "2000",
"posted": "2015-10-24",
"contact": {
    "name": "test1 mona",
    "phone": "98765678",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
},
"categories": [
    "vehicle",
    "test"
],
"image": "1.jpg",
"views": "200"
}, {
"id": "2",
"title": "test2",
"description": "test 2 test 2 test 2 test 2 test 2 ",
"price": "2000",
"posted": "2015-10-24",
"contact": {
    "name": "test2 mona",
    "phone": "98765678",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
},
"categories": [
    "vehicle",
    "test"
],
"image": "1.jpg",
"views": "200"
}, {
"id": "3",
"title": "test3",
"description": "test 3 test 3 test 3 test 3 test 3 ",
"price": "3000",
"posted": "2015-10-24",
"contact": {
    "name": "test3 mona",
    "phone": "98765678",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
},
"categories": [
    "vehicle",
    "test"
],
"image": "1.jpg",
"views": "100"
}, {
"id": "4",
"title": "test4",
"description": "test 4 test 4 test 4 test 4 test 4 ",
"price": "4000",
"posted": "2015-10-24",
"contact": {
    "name": "test4 mona",
    "phone": "98765678",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
},
"categories": [
    "vehicle",
    "test"
],
"image": "1.jpg",
"views": "40"
}, {
"id": "5",
"title": "test5",
"description": "test 5 test 5 test 5 test 5 test 5 ",
"price": "5000",
"posted": "2015-10-24",
"contact": {
    "name": "test5 mona",
    "phone": "98765678",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
},
"categories": [
    "vehicle",
    "test"
],
"image": "1.jpg",
"views": "290"
}, {
"id": "6",
"title": "test6",
"description": "test 6 test 6 test 6 test 6 test 6 ",
"price": "6000",
"posted": "2015-10-24",
"contact": {
    "name": "test6 mona",
    "phone": "98765678",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
},
"categories": [
    "vehicle",
    "test"
],
"image": "1.jpg",
"views": "10"
}]
```